# How can I order a Dictionary<string,string> by a substring within the value?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, substring, csv

I have a `Dictionary <string, string>` where the value is a concatenation of substrings delimited with a `:`. For example, `123:456:Bob:Smith`.

I would like to order the dictionary by the last substring (Smith) ascending, and preferably like this:

```
orderedDictionary = unordered
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

So, I need to somehow treat the `x.Value` as a `string` and sort by extracting the fourth substring. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to google of how to take a substring in c#? Do you really think it's not described in MSDN?

Comment: Sounds more like you need to split the string rather than use a substring

Comment: I know how to extract substrings, the issue is how to apply it to OrderBy(x => x.Value).  How does one cast x.Value to a string and whether extracting a substring from that cast would even work for the OrderBy.  Please reread my post.

Comment: That's actually what I use in other parts of the code.  I was just referring to seperate strings within a single string.  I assume a split would be used somehow.

Comment: Cast `x.Value` to a string? It's a generic dictionary - `x.Value` is already a string. `.OrderBy` will sort the current, enumerated item according to whatever you return from the lambda expression. If you returned `banana`, all items would be sorted according to that. Hence, you can do whatever you want to `x.Value`, just making sure you return the value you want to sort by.

Comment: You put me on the right track J. Steen, I figured it out.  Overthought it...  Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes, it's simpler than you think, as some of the answers point out without really saying so. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ordered = unordered.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Split(':').Last())
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
orderedDictionary = unordered.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Substring(x.Value.LastIndexOf(":"))).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `OrderBy` Method of `IDictionary`, specifically this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx noting the `comparer`parameter.  That should point you in the right direction and I think you'll find learning the remainder of benefit.

Comment: @DStanley, you can use the keySelector parameter to pick part of the value as the key no?

Comment: Deleted... I was looking at SortedDictionary.